# Android WebView flicker after calling clearView()

Tags: android, android-webview

I use a android.webkit.WebView to display some HTML formatted info to the user. Whenever I "page" in my application, I reuse all the graphical elements on screen and just fill them with different content. A WebView will by default increase its size to fit the contents, but won't decrease if the content shrinks.

To fix this, I call `webView.clearView()` to clear the view and then `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null)`to reload it with data. It works, but it creates a very strange behavior where the view starts to flicker persistently. The flickering area seems to be the same size as what would have been left empty  after filling it with smaller content.

I can't describe this better with words, so I created a short video to illustrate the problem:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yL7tQpRSFe0

The WebView is the yellow box on the lower part of the screen.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug?
If this is an Android bug, is there a better way to resize the view as to circumvent this problem?

Comment: `invalidate()` and any other way of forcing the view, or parent view to redraw doesn't seem to have any effect either.

Comment: were you able to find any solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Manish No solution I'm afraid. We ended up using an altogether different solution.

Answer (score 0):

we had an `Webview` with a `RecyclerView` on top of it. Every `notifyItemChange` call caused flickering in the `Webview`.

We got rid of it with `yourWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)`